# Can Schengen visa be issued 1 month before the start of its validity date?

Tags: visas, schengen

My parents are going to Amsterdam in April from Manila.  I'm planning to let them stay in Dubai for a month before continuing to Amsterdam.  Routing will be Manila-Dubai-Amsterdam, since they are applying for their visas in Manila, is it possible that they'd be granted a visa with a validity starting a month after it is issued?

The last time they got a Schengen visa they were advised by a travel agent to travel immediately upon issuance otherwise they said it will not be valid anymore, so I'm confused if my plan of letting them stay in Dubai for a month will be possible.

So, can a Schengen visa be issued 1 month before the start of validity date?

Comment: What kind of visa?  I mean it normally has an expiration date which is what you should be concerned about.  If a visa expires in one month then it's a concern otherwise why would it be?

Answer (score 5):

A Schengen visa does not start from the date that it's issued on, generally. The start date of the visa depends on the date of first entry into Schengen filed according the itinerary when you make your visa application, usually with a few extra days added before it in case plans change.

Answer (score 3):

[Yes](http://www.finland.org/public/default.aspx?nodeid=40963), you can apply a maximum of three months before the start of the trip:

> It is advisable to apply for a visa well in advance of the planned
>   date of travel. The application can be submitted a maximum of 3 months
>   ahead of the trip.